# Typeahead in HTML input

Tags: html, css

Are typeaheads possible in HTML inputs? As an example, typing "stack" in Chrome search bar gives a typeahead of "stackoverflow.com" as shown below, within the input.

[image]

Is it possible to do similar thing in HTML inputs as well?

Comment: Yes it is, but to implement it you certainly need javascript and probably want to look into AJAX

Comment: https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Comment: @BijanRafraf I am really ok with using JS. I googled but didnt find any solution, with or without JS

Comment: @SebastianBrosch Thanks for the link :)

Comment: @SebastianBrosch They achieved it by placing one input on the top of other and making the top input transparent. Pretty cool.